# how to make icon inside text input clickable in ionic 5

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i added an icon in a text input, the icon is supposed to be clickable but after adding inside the text input it's no more clickable

```
<ion-input (ionChange)="inputChanged($event)" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
  <ion-icon [name]='eye-outline' (click)="togglePassword()" class="suffix-icon" </ion-icon>
</ion-input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the `<icon>` element inside the `<button>` element.

```html
<ion-input (ionChange)="inputChanged($event)" [formControlName]="formCtrlName">
    <!-- In Ionic 4 version it is used as follows. -->
     <ion-button (click)="clickEventFunction($event, item.id)">
        <ion-icon [name]='eye-outline' (click)="togglePassword()" class="suffix-icon"</ion-icon>
    </ion-button>

     <!-- Used as below before "Ionic 4" release. -->
     <button (click)="clickEventFunction($event, item.id)">
        <ion-icon [name]='eye-outline' (click)="togglePassword()" class="suffix-icon"</ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-input>
```

```js
clickEventFunction(event: Event, id: any){
    /* Something */
}
```

---

###### References

- [ion-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button)
- [Ionic API Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api)

Comment: item is not known in my html

Answer (score 0):

inside you ts file take a boolean:

```
showPass: boolean = false;
```

in html:

```
<ion-item lines="none">
  <ion-input type="{{showPass ? 'text' : 'password'}}" placeholder="Password" (ionChange)="inputChanged($event)" [formControlName]="formCtrlName"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="eye-outline" slot="end" *ngIf="!showPass" (click)="showPass = !showPass"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon name="eye-off-outline" slot="end" *ngIf="showPass" (click)="showPass = !showPass"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of making a clickable icon in an ion input.

[image: password_hide_show]